# How to generate scala compiler plugin as part of the build process and use it for building subsequent projects?

Tags: scala, ant, intellij-idea, build

I have IDEA module which contains 2 projects.
First project is Scala compiler plugin, second is some other project which requires mentioned Scala plugin during build phase.
Scala plugin project contains build.xml Ant file with `build` and `clean` tasks (used for creating jar file). Normal project have dependency on the Scala plugin project.
When I'm building whole module, IntelliJ do the following tasks:

- build Scala compiler plugin project
- run Ant tasks (`clean` and then `build`) to generate Scala compiler plugin jar
- build second project

And it fails on steep 3 because it doesn't see Scala plugin jar. Error which I see look like that:
`Warning: could not load descriptor for plugin Path_to_existing_plugin_jar_file"`
This message comes from here: http://lampsvn.epfl.ch/svn-repos/scala/scala-experimental/trunk/bootstrap/src/compiler/scala/tools/nsc/plugins/Plugin.scala

I verified paths few times, they are fine. And jar file exists on hard drive.
If I disable `clean` Ant task and try to build module twice it works fine (first time it fails with exactly the same error message).

For me it looks like somehow IntelliJ/scalac try to load that Scala compiler plugin at the beginning of building module, and even if it exists later that fact is ignored.

Is there any way to fix that behavior? For some reasons I would like to build both projects in one pass.

Comment: I ended up creating my own builder: http://www.jetbrains.org/intellij/sdk/docs/reference_guide/frameworks_and_external_apis/external_builder_api.html